# How to get the entire equation to work correctly?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, line

I have written the following equation:

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
    \bigg \{2\rho-\bigg (2l+n-2-\sqrt{n^2-4l^2+4ln-4n+4}\bigg )\bigg\}
    \bigg \{2\rho-\bigg (2l+n-2+\sqrt{n^2-4l^2+4ln-4n+4}\bigg )\bigg\}\geq 0
    \end{split}
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

The lines of the equation are getting out of the margin.
I did use split and `\\` but when I use it the rest of the part of the document starts behaving abruptly
.
I start getting spaces in between the sections.
Can someone please tell me how to fix it?
Do I need to use any package??

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few options.<sup>1</sup>

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The options include \texttt{align}
\begin{align}
    \bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2-\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}&\notag\\
    \cdot\bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2+\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}&\geq 0
\end{align}
and \texttt{multline}
\begin{multline}
    \bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2-\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}\\
    \cdot\bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2+\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}\geq 0
\end{multline}
and \texttt{aligned}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    \bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2-\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}&\\
    \cdot\bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2+\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}&\geq 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
and \texttt{split}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2-\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}\\
    \cdot\bigl\{2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2+\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\bigr\}\geq 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the future, please consider posting compilable examples. `\documentclass` needs to go before `\begin{document}` and you forgot to load `amsmath`.

<sub><sup>1</sup>I personally do not like options (3) or (4), but this is just an opinion. When you have the first time a page break in an equation you may understand why.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. One question what are the alternatives for `aligned`?

Comment: @Math_Freak I added more options. (I am pretty sure there will be other answers adding a slight tilt and tell you how great this tilt is. This is what happens always these days.)

Comment: +1 But I think you forgot to introduce another one with `multlined`.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Thanks! Yes, the list is by far not exhaustive. My favorite is also missing: `\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 f_+(\ell,n)\,f_-(\ell,n)\ge0\;,
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
f_\pm(\ell,n)=2\rho-\bigl(2\ell+n-2\pm\sqrt{n^2-4\ell^2+4\ell n-4n+4}\bigr)\;.
\end{equation}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Yes. It is easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest a different way to cope with such a long formula: use an abbreviation for the expression under the square root.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}[t]
  &\bigl( 2\rho-(2l+n-2-\sqrt{\Delta}\,) \bigr)
   \bigl( 2\rho-(2l+n-2+\sqrt{\Delta}\,) \bigr)\geq 0
  \\[0.5ex]
  &\Delta=n^2-4l^2+4ln-4n+4
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

There is no need to go `\bigg`: just remember to use `\,` when the square root is followed by a parenthesis.

[image]